# Referring users the Money.SE site -- Is it possible to track signups?

Tags: support

So, I setup a Twitter account a few months ago to test for referring users to the Money.SE site. I can track the click through rates from Twitter to SE, but I'd like to be able to track the number of users that sign up using the link.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Reason I ask is that if I get a 20% click through rate from Twitter, that's great... but in the end it's meaningless unless I know that people are signing up and I'm able to tell which pitches work on a case by case basis.